# execute task in .rb file

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on a project that's been in development for quite a while now. I'm trying to figure out how everything works and my next step was how to update/fill the 'library' as it's called in the project.

I found several .rake files hidden away somewhere, but they are used in another .rb file. In said .rb file the entire logic behind the several tasks is set up, so everything happens in the right order.

Now, here's my problem: I need to use the tasks in the .rb file in order to generate the library. They're nested in namespaces and I can't figure out how to reach the tasks.

Here's a shortened version of the structure in the library.rb file:

```
namespace :library do
  task :something do
  ...
  end
  ...
  namespace :local do
  ...
    namespace :generate do
      task :default do
      ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I want to reach the task :default.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

EDIT:
The command `rake library:local:generate:default` gives an error:

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'library:local:generate:default'
```

EDIT: I can't change the file's names, extentions or locations. Library.rb is currently located in `config/deploy/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you would like to run the rake task from the command line, in which case you would enter `rake library:local:generate:default`.

You also need to require your `library.rb` file to make the task available. You can do that with the `-f` flag on the rake command. So, for example: `rake -f path/to/library.rb library:local:generate:default`.

Comment: That gives me the error `Rake aborted! Don't know how to build task 'library:local:generate:default'`.

Comment: That's because you need to require your library.rb file to make the task available. You can do that with the `-f` flag on the `rake` command. So, for example: `rake -f path/to/library.rb library:local:generate:default`.

Comment: That works! Thanks a lot! If you include it in your answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

A fast solution could be rename the file with `.rake` extension and put the file under lib/task so you can call it with rake `namespace:task`

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot do that. I can't make any big changes. I just need to figure out how the other team has been doing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace :library do
  task :something do
  ...
  end
  ...
  namespace :local do
  ...
    namespace :generate do
      task default: :environment do
      ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You forgot to add environment to it. Try the same rake task command again:

```
rake library:local:generate:default
```

This might help you

Comment: You misread my question, I did not make the file and have no problems there. I just needed the command to execute the task (which theunraveler  helped me with) and was showing the structure of the namespaces.